# Tabulator remote filtering empties the input fields

Tags: tabulator

Something i noticed, when you filter remote Tabulator doesn't save the queries and empties the searchfields in the top bar. (photo below)

I've added the base of my table.

Couldn't find anything in the documentation or on the internet, so tought i ask here, is this right? Or is this a "bug"?

Do you know a fix how i could get the values back in the inputboxes?

[image: these inputfields]

```
var table = new Tabulator("#table", {
        layout: "fitColumns",
        filterMode: "remote",
        dataSendParams: {
             filter: 'filter_by',
             sort: 'order_by',
        },
        ajaxURL: "{url}",
        columns: [
            {
                title: 'Username',
                field: 'user_name',
                headerFilter: 'input'
            },
            {
                title: "Birthdate",
                field: "birth_date",
                headerFilter: "input"
            }
        ],
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If i return the filters and feed them to this function it fills the fields with the queries.

Not the cleanest option and it would be nice to have it native. But it does the job.

```
    table.on("dataProcessed", function(filters, rows) {
        filters.forEach(function(filter) {
            filterFields = document.querySelectorAll("[tabulator-field='" + filter.field + "'] > .tabulator-col-content > .tabulator-header-filter > input");
            filterFields.forEach(function(element) {
                element.placeholder = filter.value;
            });
        });
    });
```